# Ordering by multiple columns which include numerical data and timestamp

Tags: r

I am trying to sort a very large dataset that includes id numbers and timestamps. There are multiple rows with the same ID number and therefore I need the corresponding timestamps to be in datetime order. I have tried both the base order() and the dplyr arrange() functions.
Example of the base order() function code:

```
> df[with(df, order("deviceNr", "timestamp"))]
```

This code seemed to remove all parts of the dataset and produced two columns of ascending numbers

Example of the dplyr arrange() function code:

```
 > arrange(df, "deviceNr", "timestamp")
```

This code arranged only by deviceNr (the ID), but not by timestamp

Comment: In base, you're missing the comma to show that you are ordering rows: `df[with(df, order("deviceNr", "timestamp")), ]` adding the `,` inside `[]`.

Comment: @GregorThomas the quote is still not correct in `base R`

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

We don't quoted the column names in `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(df, deviceNr, timestamp)
```

Or use `across` which can take both quoted and unquoted

```
arrange(df, across(c('deviceNr', 'timestamp')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the code below if you still want to use `order`

```
df[with(df, order(deviceNr, timestamp)),]
```